# why isn't the \n special character not creating a new line in txt file using php

Tags: php, text, newline

Im writing to a file using php, and i have no idea why in the text file the "\n" special character is not creating a newline, why?

Comment: Please post the code you're using here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `\n` doesn't always imply a newline :

- UNIX / Linux use `\n` *([Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline))* for linebreaks
- Mac *(before OSX)* used `\r` *([Carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return))*
- And windows uses a combinaison of both

Also note that those `\n` and `\r` characters will work in double-quoted strings -- but not in single-quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use constant [PHP_EOL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) instead of `\n`. PHP_EOL should be used to find the newline character in a cross-platform-compatible way, so it handles DOS/Mac/Unix issues.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same until i realized that

'\n' in single quotes is a literal \n.

"\n" in double quotes is interpreted as a line break.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php